# T SQL CAST a CASE Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting

Using SQL Server 2014.  How do I CAST the result of a CASE statement?  I need to CAST to nvarchar(20)

This is my code:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN [AddressLine1] LIKE 'ABC%'
            THEN REPLACE([AddressLine1], 'ABC', '')
        WHEN [AddressLine1] LIKE 'SCHEME%'
            THEN REPLACE([AddressLine1], 'QWE,', '')
        WHEN [AddressLine1] LIKE 'SBLOCK%'
            THEN REPLACE([AddressLine1], 'QWE', '')
        WHEN [AddressLine1] LIKE 'QAZ%'
            THEN REPLACE([AddressLine1], 'QAZ', '')
        ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM([AddressLine1]))
        END AS cast(search_name AS nvarchar(20)) as search_name
from myTable;
```

But I keep receiving the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'search_name'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast around the whole result of the case.

```
SELECT cast(CASE 
        WHEN [AddressLine1] LIKE 'ABC%'
            THEN REPLACE([AddressLine1], 'ABC', '')
        WHEN [AddressLine1] LIKE 'SCHEME%'
            THEN REPLACE([AddressLine1], 'QWE,', '')
        WHEN [AddressLine1] LIKE 'SBLOCK%'
            THEN REPLACE([AddressLine1], 'QWE', '')
        WHEN [AddressLine1] LIKE 'QAZ%'
            THEN REPLACE([AddressLine1], 'QAZ', '')
        ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM([AddressLine1]))
        END as nvarchar(20))  AS search_name
from myTable;
```

Comment: It works thanks, although you have AS in twice (AS as search_name)

Comment: Well spotted. Have removed the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `cast` the whole case expression to do conversation :

If you want `search_name` as searchable then you can use `apply` :

```
SELECT t.*, CAST(search_name AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS search_name 
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (CASE WHEN [AddressLine1] LIKE 'ABC%'
                    THEN REPLACE([AddressLine1], 'ABC', '')
                    WHEN [AddressLine1] LIKE 'SCHEME%'
                    THEN REPLACE([AddressLine1], 'QWE,', '')
                    WHEN [AddressLine1] LIKE 'SBLOCK%'
                    THEN REPLACE([AddressLine1], 'QWE', '')
                    WHEN [AddressLine1] LIKE 'QAZ%'
                    THEN REPLACE([AddressLine1], 'QAZ', '')
                    ELSE LTRIM([AddressLine1]) -- removed RTRIM()  
              END)
     ) tt(search_name);
```

By this way, you can search by `search_name` easily don't need to use sub-query or avoid repetition of `case` expression.

Note : I have removed `RTRIM()` as `SQL Server` will ignore right spaces while comparing the strings.